# Find the number of solutions of the equation $\sec x + \csc x = \sqrt{15}$ in the interval $0$ to $2\pi$.

Tags: trigonometry

Find the number of solutions of the equation $\sec x + \csc x  =  \sqrt{15}$ in the interval $0$ to $2\pi$.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: converted in sine & cosine and squared on both side...but squaring leads to extra solutions..how to check

Comment: Put in the extra-solutions in the original equation and check if they solve it.

Comment: Set $$\sin x+\cos x=u\implies\sin x\cos x=\dfrac{u^2-1}2$$

Answer (score 5):

Rewrite the equation as
$$
\cos x+\sin x=\sqrt{15}\cos x\sin x
$$
Set $X=\cos x$ and $Y=\sin x$; then you have the equivalent system
$$
\begin{cases}
X+Y=\sqrt{15}\,XY\\[4px]
X^2+Y^2=1
\end{cases}
$$
Remember that $X^2+Y^2=(X+Y)^2-2XY$, so the second equation becomes
$$
15X^2Y^2-2XY-1=0
$$
Set $XY=t$, so we have $15t^2-2t-1=0$, that gives
$$
t=\frac{1+4}{15}=\frac{1}{3}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
t=\frac{1-4}{15}=-\frac{1}{5}
$$
Now you have to solve the simpler systems
$$
\begin{cases}
X+Y=\sqrt{15}/3 \\[4px]
XY=1/3
\end{cases}
\qquad\qquad
\begin{cases}
X+Y=-\sqrt{15}/5 \\[4px]
XY=-1/5
\end{cases}
$$

The first is solved with the equation
$$
z^2-\frac{\sqrt{15}}{3}z+\frac{1}{3}=0
$$
whose roots are
$$
\frac{\sqrt{15}\pm\sqrt{3}}{6}
$$
so we get the two solutions
$$
\begin{cases}
X=\dfrac{\sqrt{15}+\sqrt{3}}{6}\\[6px]
Y=\dfrac{\sqrt{15}-\sqrt{3}}{6}
\end{cases}
\qquad
\begin{cases}
X=\dfrac{\sqrt{15}-\sqrt{3}}{6}\\[6px]
Y=\dfrac{\sqrt{15}+\sqrt{3}}{6}
\end{cases}
$$
that determine $x$.

Similarly for the second system.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sec x + \csc x  =  \sqrt{15}$$
$$\frac{1}{\cos x}+\frac{1}{\sin x}=\sqrt{15}$$
$$\sin x+ \cos x=\sqrt{15} \sin x \cos x$$
$$\sin^2 x+2 \sin x \cos x+ \cos^2 x=15 \sin^2 x \cos^2 x$$
$$1 +2 \sin x \cos x =15 \sin^2 x \cos^2 x$$
$$\sin x \cos x =t$$
$$15t^2-2t-1=0$$
$t=-\frac 15$ or $t=\frac 13$

$\sin x \cos x =-\frac 15$ or $\sin x \cos x =\frac 13$

$2\sin x \cos x =-\frac 25$ or $2\sin x \cos x =\frac 23$

$\sin 2x =-\frac 25$ or $\sin 2x =\frac 23$

$$x=(-1)^{n+1} \frac 12 \arcsin \frac 25 + \frac {\pi n}{2}$$ or

$$x=(-1)^{k} \frac 12 \arcsin \frac 23 + \frac {\pi k}{2}$$

Comment: This will give extra solutions..

Comment: @Aashish: answer -- 4